# Android Debug Apk Obfuscation using Proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, signing

I am using Eclipse integrated ProGuard for obfuscating my application apk.

I have tried exporting signed packages for my application. The APK gets installed but doesn't work properly (with or without Proguard obfuscation)

However, there is a debug signed APK generated by eclipse, which is working absolutely fine.
Is there a way to obfuscate that APK?

I need to get a properly working signed, obfuscated APK not for release but for internal sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have opened the project properties and uncommented this line

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

i will suggest you to go through this link, before implementing proguard:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/limitations.html

Comment: but that is what Proguard manual says for Android apps built using Eclipse. It advises to uncomment the line and then fix warnings.

Anyways, thats not my problem. My problem is that the exported signed APK does not work (With or Without Proguard). I want to obfuscate the debug apk.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse build process and the Ant build process in the Android SDK never obfuscate debug apks. You can try fixing your Eclipse export (e.g. based on error messages in the logcat) or building a release with Ant.